# ExtJs is sending bad header on submit on 'Ext.form.field.file'

Tags: asp.net, extjs, http-headers

so as mentioned above I am uploading a file through ExtJs using `Ext.form.field.file`. However, when I do it, it sends the following header `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`. This is causing issues on my back-end (ASP.NET) which thinking that HTML is expected is putting  tags around the JSON causing problems when the response comes back (haven't gotten an answer how to fix this on the ASP.NET side Does anyone have any idea how to modify this header either when sending the request on the ExtJs side or in an ASP.NET controller?

Comment: you need to return HTML for ext's file uploader. read the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Neil mentioned it actually is expecting HTML to return because it is using hidden iFrame to do its work. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload

Comment: I am not sure I am following what this link says, the response should be in HTML? When I forcefully send JSON back by changing the return type in the controller to String and manually write out the JSON everything works fine. What should the format of the HTML be?

Comment: That's right you can send back JSON as a string if you need it. Just set the content type to be text/html render("{success:true}")

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the headers you want to send when you submit you form as follow:

```
your_form.submit({
    url: 'file-upload',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { Accept : 'what you want' }, 
    success: ....
});
```

I didn´t tested but I´m pretty sure it works.

Comment: Already tried this, I actually read somewhere on an ExtJs forum that headers can't be changed for file uploads.